Golang S3 Upload Returning Download Link
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. It seems pretty straightforward, but the link I'm returning is a DOWNLOAD link, not an inline viewing link. Everywhere I look I find the same answer: set the content type. I did that and still the same. I'm not sure if it changes anything, but I'm using MinIO S3 through Heroku, which is apparently S3 compatible.
func UploadImageToS3(file []byte, fileName string, contentType string) (string, error) {
    bucket := aws.String(config.RetrieveEnv("S3_BUCKET"))
    key := aws.String(fmt.Sprintf("images/%s", fileName))

    // create a new session
    s3Config := &aws.Config{
        Credentials:      credentials.NewStaticCredentials(config.RetrieveEnv("S3_ACCESS_KEY"), config.RetrieveEnv("S3_SECRET_KEY"), ""),
        Endpoint:         aws.String(config.RetrieveEnv("S3_ENDPOINT")),
        Region:           aws.String(config.RetrieveEnv("S3_REGION")),
        DisableSSL:       aws.Bool(false),
        S3ForcePathStyle: aws.Bool(true),
    }

    newSession, err := session.NewSession(s3Config)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    s3Client := s3.New(newSession)

    _, err = s3Client.PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:             bucket,
        Key:                key,
        Body:               aws.ReadSeekCloser(bytes.NewReader(file)),
        ContentDisposition: aws.String(fmt.Sprintf("inline; filename=%s", fileName)),
        ContentType:        aws.String(contentType),
        ACL:                aws.String("public-read"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/%s/%s", config.RetrieveEnv("S3_ENDPOINT"), *bucket, *key), nil
}


@AnonCoward I actually want inline, not attachment

To understand why it's not being embedded, we'll have to see the page-side code. The issue likely has nothing to do with this function, but rather how it's used in the calling function.

privided your s3 (or in your case minio) bucket is configured for public access, the URL is:
https://${S3_ENDPOINT}/${S3_BUCKET}/${key}

«Everywhere I look I find the same answer: set the content type»–no, it should be "set content-dispositon" (which you're doing). The things to checks: 1) go to AWS S3 console and see the details of the object you upload–do they have expected content-disposition; 2) check that S3 does indeed return correct content-disposition when a file you've uploaded is fetched (DevTools in a browser, curl -i etc).

Which content type do you use?

i did it this way
    req, _ := d.s3Client.GetObjectRequest(
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket:                     aws.String(d.bucket),
            Key:                        aws.String(clPath),
            ResponseContentDisposition: aws.String("inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""),
            ResponseContentType:        aws.String(contentType),
        },
    )

    err := req.Build()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to build get obj request: %w", err)
    }

    return req.HTTPRequest.URL.String(), nil

this code will generate such url
https://host/bucket/path?response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D"128x128.jpg"&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg

